# Cloudwatch alarms from Amazon AWS EC2 instance are always in UT, how can I change the alarm time zone to Eastern?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am running an Amazon linux AMI and the alarms that I've setup are coming in all showing UT (universal time).  It is inconvenient reading these alarms and I'd like them setup to read in eastern time zone (or America/New_York).

I've already set my /etc/localtime to point to -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York

```
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
```

But it is still sending alarms in the UT timezone.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CloudWatch uses universal time to record metrics. (As it ought to. Consider servers and people located in different time zones, different DST change dates, not to mention the insanity of DST itself. As in aviation, UT is the only reasonable way to cope.)

So the CloudWatch system uses UT. This is independent of the systems being monitored. Which is why changing the TZ on your server didn't have an effect.

It's understandable that you may want Amazon's console web app to report the times shifted to local TZ. Unfortunately Amazon just doesn't offer that AFIK. Some third-party apps like Ylastic might (but might cost extra money).

Comment: I'll just have to learn how to deal with the times in UTC I guess.

Comment: Nail on the head. Indeed Ylastic supports this, it's under Settings > Timezone.

Answer (score 1):

The time format the CloudWatch uses is UTC. I think we can not change this timezone. it would be nice if they could allow us to change, but as of now, they dont allow us to change...

Answer (score 0):

please refer to link
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/customize-amazon-cloudwatch-alarm-notifications-to-your-local-time-zone-part-1/

it's using lambda to modify it

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/510209)